# Android sync with calendar works only one-way

Tags: sync, google-calendar

I have a Phone with Android 4.1 Jelly Bean and I am trying to synchronize my calendar with my Google account. The problem is, that sync only works one-way. Data from Google are transferred to my phone, but events from my mobile calendar don't upload to Google account. I tried various settings but I am obviously missing something.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Have you verified that the calendar events that you created are marked as being on your Google Calendar and not a local calendar(e.g. My Calendar)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed by giving the mobile calendar the same name as its called on Google...